# Dropping images coming from a certain file inside our map

Tags: leaflet

I've been charged of this yesterday :

- Finding a way for the user to drag a picture that he took before and dropping inside the map element
- this picture is coming from an outside file like `D:\images\image.png`

I want to know (and I've been looking for this but I found nothing) if there's a way to do such a thing with leaflet (maybe the `ImageOverlay` and JavaScript)

Is there a way to make an image that came form your hardrive/USB an drop it inside the map ?